# Datatables mysql details external file

Tags: mysql, datatables

I am using multiple tables with multiple MySQL tables. For this, I am using data tables server-side processing. Is there any way to use different table from single server-proecssing.php and create different tables?

Right now i made the clone of server-processing.php (serverprocessing1.php, serverprocessing2.php) to make the different table. I want to add mysql on single file so I can change easily.

This is my code

```
    <?php

/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

// DB table to use
$table = 'new';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'name', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'country',  'dt' => 1 ),


);

require( 'mysql.php' );


);

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

and this is mysql.php

```
$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => '123',
'db'   => 'doo',
'host' => 'localhost'
```

I used php open and close tag but its giving error.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: are you really missing closing parenthesis in mysql.php or is it a mistake?

Comment: that i added on first code.